# What to use and expose for Web Application Auto Ids, GUIDs or Auto Ids + GUIDs?

Tags: web-applications, auto-increment, guid

I was researching around and I really can't make up my mind. I was creating databases and building applications only with auto increment IDs, but this is my first serious startup project that may grow.

So I need your thoughts on the things written below or some best practice examples or open source projects from which I can see how its done.

Firstly I will start with this, which was the final puzzle that blow up my mind.
Because of researching, and reading about exposing incremented IDs, for one of the competitors(Competitor A) I found out how many clients they have and even how many projects are created, yes, because IDs were exposed, but from the other side another competitor (Competitor B) is using GUIDs to identify their objects, so I couldn't know anything.

**So competition conclusion:**

- Having auto increment IDs is bad because of competition, they would know how my business is progressing
- Having GUIDs, competition will not know how my business is progressing based on IDs

**Some speed and storage conclusions:**

- Having auto increment IDs is faster and is most light weight for relationships
- Having GUIDs is slower and relationships become heavier

**Exposing of IDs thoughts:**

- Exposing auto increment IDs will only expose to competition how my business is progressing, what would be other security problems? (I really can't think of any...)
- Exposing GUIDs is safe, but they are kinda ugly...

So this only leaves me with some facts, I can't produce any meaningful strategy, this is the best conclusions I have made so far:

1. Every table will have Auto Incremented ID Column that will uniquely present a record
2. In case of exposure I will use second ID Column with GUID or maybe obfuscation procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Increase you ids not by ++ but by random number, like random(1000), your competitors will die of jealousy

Comment: hahahaha, to be honest that's not my biggest concern, but i still think that its valid argument, because I proved it right on my competitor web app